# Django test runner fails in virtualenv on Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv, python-unittest

I've been struggling with a problem with the Django test runner installed in a Python virtualenv on Ubuntu 14.04.  The same software runs fine on MacOS, and I think it was fine on an earlier version of Ubuntu.

The failure message is:

```
ImportError: '<test>' module incorrectly imported from '<base-env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package-dir>'. Expected '<base-env>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package-dir>'. Is this module globally installed?
```

And the full stack trace from the error is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
      sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
      utility.execute()
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
      self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
      super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
      self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
      super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
      output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
      failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 147, in run_tests
      suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
    File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 96, in build_suite
      tests = self.test_loader.discover(start_dir=label, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 206, in discover
      tests = list(self._find_tests(start_dir, pattern))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 287, in _find_tests
      for test in self._find_tests(full_path, pattern):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 287, in _find_tests
      for test in self._find_tests(full_path, pattern):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 267, in _find_tests
      raise ImportError(msg % (mod_name, module_dir, expected_dir))
  ImportError: 'test_entity' module incorrectly imported from '/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/annalist_root/annalist/tests'. Expected '/home/annalist/anenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/annalist_root/annalist/tests'. Is this module globally installed?
```

The test cases run fine in the development environment, and they also run fine when installed from a source distribution kit into a new virtualenv environment on the MAcOS development host.  But when I install the same package into a new virtualenv on an Ubuntu 14.04 host, the test runner fails with the above message.

The problems came up in a management utility I created that invokes some functions of `django-admin` (as well as some other stuff).

Web searches revealed reports of bugs with virtualenv and posix compatibility, which have been addressed relatively recently (2013/14) in Ubuntu distributions by creating a `local` directory in the virtual environment which in turn contains symlinks to directories that are also accessible from the top-level virtual environment directory.  The paths shown in the error message correspond to these aliased directory paths.

(I'm posting this as a question so I can post the outcome and answer from my investigations, in the hope that it might be useful to others.  Hence, I'm not trying to give a detailed description of my particular software setup.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

The fix in my code was to use `os.path.realpath` to get a canonicalized version of the installed package path, and pass this value on the command line that invokes the `django-admin` utility.  In my case it looks something like this:

```
approot = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

and:

```
with ChangeCurrentDir(approot):
    subprocess_command = (
        "django-admin test --pythonpath=%s --settings=%s --top-level-directory=%s"%
            (approot, settings_module_name, approot)
        )
    status = subprocess.call(subprocess_command.split())
```

(where `ChangeCurrentDir` is a context handler that runs the enclosed code with a specified current working directory).

### More details

Some further experimentation showed that I could "fix" the problem by strategic replacement of `os.path.abspath` with `os.path.realpath` in the Python and/or Django library code.

The core problem I found was in:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py
```

Specifically:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 267, in _find_tests
    raise ImportError(msg % (mod_name, module_dir, expected_dir))
ImportError: 'test_entity' module incorrectly imported from ...
```

The offending code in `loader.py`leading up to this is:

```
        if realpath.lower() != fullpath_noext.lower():
            module_dir = os.path.dirname(realpath)
            mod_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(full_path))[0]
            expected_dir = os.path.dirname(full_path)
            msg = ("%r module incorrectly imported from %r. Expected %r. "
                   "Is this module globally installed?")
            raise ImportError(msg % (mod_name, module_dir, expected_dir))
```

If I replace the `if` statement with this:

```
        if os.path.realpath(realpath).lower() != fullpath_noext.lower():
```

Then everything is happy.  This confirms that it is a symlink aliasing problem, as  `os.path.realpath()` resolves any symlinks to the underlying path.  But this is not a solution for an installable software package, as it involves modifying the underlying Python installation.  So, having probed the underlying problem, I need for something more accessible to attack.

Next port of call was the Django test runner library, which is installed in the virtual environment.

```
<base-env>/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py
```

In particular, focusing on this part of the stack trace:

```
  File "/home/annalist/anenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 96, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.discover(start_dir=label, **kwargs)
```

Digging around this code, I was able to identify the problem was related to the `label` parameter, which defaults to `'.'` (i.e. current directory).  No easy fix is apparent here, but it suggests the problem may be related to the current directory and/or path used when running `django-admin`.  This led to the above solution (which may be overkill - I'm not sure that the `--pythonpath=` option is needed, but it is working for me).

Answer (score 33):

I had exactly the same problem and couldn't figure out what was going on. Finally it was a stupid thing:

I had a layout similar to this one:

```
my_app/
    __init__.py
    tests.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
       test_foo.py
```

The problem was generated by having both a "tests.py" module and a "tests" package in the same folder.

Just deleting the "tests.py" file solved the problem for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice... saved me a headache :)

Comment: Oh man, I was about 5 minutes from going into angry-developer-mode. Such a small thing, thanks! Saved me from a long and grumpy day!