# Testing Django in a Virtual Environment

Tags: django, testing, virtualenv

I have a Django project setup under virtualenv, and have a empty tests.py under the project folder.

When I do "python manage.py test", I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/oicms/test/oicms_test_runner.py", line 209, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/oicms/test/oicms_test_runner.py", line 150, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.discover(start_dir=label, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 206, in discover
    tests = list(self._find_tests(start_dir, pattern))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 267, in _find_tests
    raise ImportError(msg % (mod_name, module_dir, expected_dir))
ImportError: 'tests' module incorrectly imported from '/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/dj_prj'. Expected '/Users/dj_prj/dj_prj/'. Is this module globally installed?
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your environment?

Your problem may be related to this one:

[Django test runner fails in virtualenv on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775185/django-test-runner-fails-in-virtualenv-on-ubuntu)